# how to make groove on the mesh

Tags: mesh

With the reference image im trying to make a groove on my mesh. Like this

[image]

[image]

With the red mark twisted and turn its having a groove.

I have made a similar mesh and trying to slice it and make a groove. But its not creating a groove. I have given thickness to the mesh yet to know solution. Well i do not know my idea is successful or any other idea or suggestion. Thanks

**I tried like this**

[image]